# How can I center iframe and make it responsive for mobile?

Tags: html, css, iframe, youtube-iframe-api

I'm trying to make a video responsive for both desktop and mobile but whatever I do, it doesn't meet what I need. I added `text-align:center;` to the code but it also doesn't work.

I'm only using inline CSS, HTML, div tags. Provided below is a code that I have used, unfortunately, it still fails.

```
<div style="text-align:center;width:100%;" >
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zqU49pgewPg" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

What happens is that it would overlap on my website and mobile devices.

My expected outcome is to have it in the center. I'm not sure how I can do that since I have also tried `.videoWrapper` as well and it turned out to look small and it aligned to the left.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```css
.wrap {
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
}

.frame {
  width: 600pc;
  height: 560pc;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <iframe class="frane" src="https://vg.no" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and let me know is it satisfied you? -

```
<div style="text-align:center;width:100%;" >
    <iframe width="100%" height="315"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zqU49pgewPg"
        frameborder="0"
        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-    picture" allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
</div>
```